# Xcode 6.0.1 iOS 8 simulator not able to access : Unable to boot device in current state: Creating

Tags: xcode, xcode6, ios-simulator

This error is always happening:

> Unable to boot device in current state: Creating

I have tried many more but last two days no result.

[image: Screenshot and additional grammatical changes]

Comment: Please take the time to write good questions - typos in the question and lack of details (what OS version, what steps reproduce the error, what have you tried to fix it) make it hard to answer

Comment: May happen with any version, from Xcode 6.0 to Xcode 9.4 and maybe future versions as well. This issue is unrelated to iOS version: it is specific to Simulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue that can be caused by renaming Xcode.app or deleting an older Xcode.app and later running one at a different location.  The "new" Xcode.app was trying to create a device but certain data needed to create the device was unavailable (because Xcode.app was deleted), and we leave the device in that state and force manual resolution to avoid possible data loss by automatically deleting the device.

I suggest you reboot to make sure you are in a clean state and then run 'xcrun simctl erase [device udid]' where you can determine the udid by running 'xcrun simctl list'

Answer (score 4):

You will need to delete this device from your simulator and recreate it.

- From inside the iOS Simulator application menu, choose ***Hardware > Device > Manage Devices***
- In the Simulators list on the left, select the device that is unable to boot and press the delete key

Now use the + in the bottom left to add a new device with the same hardware / OS configuration.

**NOTE:** If your simulator complains it cannot find the iOS 8 simulator, and you are sure you have it installed, try rebooting your computer.  After rebooting, follow the steps above.

Comment: had something similar. Reinstalled Xcode and rebooted to fix. Suspect issue may have been caused by having two renamed installs for Xcode 6.2 beta 5 and 6.3 beta.

Comment: Hey!!  You can't delete a device that is in state creating!!! grrr.  So this can't and doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the simulator, I was able to solve the issue with those steps:

1. Close Xcode and Simulator
2. Restart the CoreSimulator service:

   ```
   sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
   ```

If it's not enough, you can also unpair/delete whatever Apple Watch is paired with your iPhone Simulator, then repeat the steps 1 and 2 above.

And after that the error "*Unable to boot device in current state: Creating*" should be gone.