# Unable to boot device in current state : Creating

Tags: xcode6, ios-simulator, runtime-error

I'm getting an error while running an application in Xcode 6 for iOS 8 simulator. The error states that **'Unable to boot device in current state: Creating'**. I have tried to reset the content of simulator. Also, I have rebooted mac after installing Xcode 6. What might be fix?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 6.0.1 iOS 8 simulator not able to access : Unable to boot device in current state: Creating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26039874/xcode-6-0-1-ios-8-simulator-not-able-to-access-unable-to-boot-device-in-curren)

Comment: @OrangeDog : How about otherway round?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is mentioned in the [Xcode 6.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-DontLinkElementID_23)

> Simulated devices can get stuck in a “Creating” state in some
>   circumstances. This problem can occur either when creating new devices
>   or when resetting existing devices after having renamed Xcode.app.
>   If this this problem occurs, reboot your system and reset the device
>   from the command line by running `xcrun simctl erase <Device UDID>.` You
>   can obtain the UDID of the device by checking the output of `xcrun simctl list`.

Comment: Then you get `Unable to erase contents and settings in current state: Creating`.

Comment: Please try with Xcode 6.2 beta.  You can also just delete the device and recreate it.

Comment: This answer didn't work for me.  The devices shown in the list, xcrun simctl list, could not be deleted because they were invalid, according to the error, grrr

Comment: Yes, they can't be erased if they are invalid.  You should just delete the invalid ones.

Comment: Worked for me in Xcode 9.3.1. Deleting in the simulator list, however, did not.

Answer (score 9):

This problem happened to me when I renamed Xcode app from 'Xcode 2.app' to 'Xcode6.app' (I have both 5 & 6 Xcodes installed)

This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26151149/2764408

> You will need to delete this device from your simulator and recreate it.
>
> From inside the iOS Simulator application menu, choose Hardware > Device > Manage Devices
>
> In the Simulators list on the left, select the device that is unable to boot and press the delete key
>
> Now use the + in the bottom left to add a new device with the same hardware / OS configuration.

Comment: I just quit the Xcode and then remove all derrived data. Then relaunch Xcode and do cleaning, build it wait for it's indexing complete then run the project and issue get resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error, I believe the problem was that I had wrong version of XCode command line tools selected (an older one).

```
# Use command line tools from Xcode.app (or correct path if not in standard location)
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/
```

After this you can try to repair the simulator device or just remove it and create a new one.

Repairing can in at least some cases be done with `xcrun` command by `upgrade`, `shutdown` etc. ocmmands

First list devices and runtime versions you have

```
xcrun simctl list
```

Then copy the simulator UUID from the list and try to shutdown.

```
xcrun simctl shutdown 43B7241F-CA66-4259-9B15-B3BAAB655779
```

If that does not work you can try other commands. I'm not sure which eventually resolved my problem. It may have been the upgrade.

From the list pick the newest iOS version (The version meant to be used with your XCode version should be visible if all is well.)

```
xcrun simctl upgrade 43B7241F-CA66-4259-9B15-B3BAAB655779 "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-4"
```

I even did erase, but I don't think that is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this issue by `xcrun simctl shutdown all` in the terminal.